# change of chi2 with Monte Carlo

Tags: chi-squared-test, monte-carlo

I am reaching out to open this topic in order to clarify a point regarding chi-square and the influence of Monte Carlo on it.

For purely informative purposes, I have decided to generate random data that follows the relationship *y=x* with noise in the following manner:

- *x* sampled from uniform([0,1])
- *sig_y* sampled from uniform([0.05, 0.5])
- *y = x +* normal(0, sig_y)

Thus, I have a nice noisy sample of my *y=x* relationship. Then, I fit a line *y = mx+b* and calculate the chi-square per degree of freedom (chi2/dof). As expected, it is close to 1 (fig.1).

[image: Basic distribution and fit.]

Subsequently, I decide to perform a Monte Carlo. This means that I will update each y point by randomly drawing from a normal distribution centered on y with a standard deviation of sig_y. Thus, I update:

- *y' =*  normal(y, sig_y)

As before, I perform a fit on this updated data, and I find a chi2/dof around 2. The fit, however, is very good despite the additional noise (fig.2).

[image: Distributuion and fit after 1 redraw]

I repeat this process a hundred times to verify this, and to my surprise, the distribution of my chi2/dof for each random draw of Monte Carlo is around 2 (fig.3).

[image: chi2/dof distribution for 100 redraws]

Is this expected? I was anticipating to also obtain a chi2/dof = 1, but that is not the case. Is there something wrong with my approach? Should I update my uncertainties sig_y during the redraw?

Thank you in advance for your assistance, and have a great day!

Comment: It sounds like you are starting with a noisy $y$ and adding more noise to it.  When the variance of the original noise is $1$ and the variance of the new noise is close to $1,$ then the variance of your "updated" $y$ must be close to $2.$  If that's not clear, iterate your procedure and observe how your chi-squared ratio keeps increasing by about $1$ with each iteration.

Comment: Oh, with that in mind I believe I actually need to update the uncertainties of my point by a factor sqrt(2). I don't know if that's the best approach but this would make sense since y~N(N(x, sigma), sigma)~N(x,sqrt(2)*sigma). 
I don't know if it's the way to proceed but it actually works!